# Link with target="_blank" does not open in new tab

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have an ASP.NET page that is combined with AngularJS. I have some links in it. All the links have the `target="_blank"` attribute. In addition, the `<body>` tag has an `ng-app` attribute.

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  @Html.ActionLink("SomeLink", "SomeAction", "SomeController", null, new { target = "_blank" })
  <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
  ...
</body>
```

What confuses me is that the first ('internal') link is opened in new tab while the second ('external') is opened in current tab (both Chrome and Firefox behaves like this). I suppose it's something inside AngularJS code, but have no idea.

I have also another page, where only the `ng-app` is different: `ng-app="MyAnotherApp"`. This one works as expected - all links are opened in new tab.

Thanks for any advice.

**UPDATE**

Links are rendered equally in both pages:

```
<a href="/SomeApp/SomeController/SomeAction" target="_blank">SomeLink</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

But despite this fact both links are opened in different way.

What part of the web app decides that new tab will be opened? The browser and the scripts or the server? I was thinking about if there is any mechanism in AngularJS that can influence whether the link is opened in new/current tab - different `ng-app` leads me to this idea.

Comment: If it's working fine in another ng-app, then there must be a difference between those two links that isn't being conveyed in your example

Answer (score 0):

After hours of fighting I found [this](https://gist.github.com/niklas-r/cf82c259f8305bc3770c) site with this piece of code:

```
angular.module('stopEvents', [])
.directive('stopEvent', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind(attr.stopEvent, function (e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        });
      }
    };
 });
```

This let me find this piece of code in our solution:

```
MyApp.directive("a", ["$window", function ($window) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.click(function () {
                if (element.attr("href") && element.attr("href").indexOf("http") === 0) {
                    $window.location.href = element.attr("href");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Whenever any link in page with `<body ng-app="MyApp">` is clicked, it looks at `href` attribute and if the address starts with http(s) (external links), default behavior (opening of new tab) is cancelled and current window is 'redirected' to the address.